# Can I have a fixed-angle sprite with a non-fixed-angle CircleCollider2D?

Tags: unity, rotation, physics, platformer

In Unity2D, can I have a fixed-angle sprite with a non-fixed-angle CircleCollider2D?

I would like to move my character using the circle physics (without fixed-angle), but display him always as if he wasn't rotated (as if he had fixed-angle).

I thought I could just let the collider rotate, and then rotate-back the sprite in the `LateUpdate`, however since the collider's center isn't `0,0`, it "rotates sideway" and doesn't end up in the "original" position.

My knowledge on matrices and quaterions is null, and trigonometry is only slightly above zero, so I'm a bit at a loss... how can I achieve the desired effect?

---

In order to prevent a X/Y problem, I want to do that since with box colliders sometimes the characters got stuck: if a platform had even just 1 pixel step, the character couldn't walk over it. Also, slopes were a big problem. Changing the collider to a Circle was the obvious consequence; I also tried to detect and add a small vertical speed but it didn't work very well and was becoming a mess.

Comment: I don't know Unity, but I think a picture would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just turn off the SpriteRenderer script so only your invisible collider still there and rotating, then make a new separate Sprite game object just for displaying the character. (Make sure this separate sprite is not a child of your collider or they will still rotate together.) Then attach a script that keep updating Sprite's transform.position to the same of your rotating collider.

Comment: Yes, I was on this route lately – didn't work at first for some reason, and I'm debugging that. If I manage to make it work, I'll accept this answer, meanwhile I'll wait for other tips.

Comment: It worked, but I had to set the `CircleCollider` center to `0,0` and pivot the `Sprite` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve created script to set each frame rotation on SpriteRenderer to zero. Works for me.

```
public class YourObject: MonoBehaviour
{

    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        spriteRenderer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }

}
```